# Spring mapping form's action to the controller

Tags: spring

I am new to the Spring Framework and I have created a controller with the method

```
@RequestMapping("/fetch/{contactId}")
public String getContact(@PathVariable("contactId") Long contactId,
        Map<String, Object> map, HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) {

    Contact contact = contactService.get(contactId);
    map.put("contact", contact);
    return "contact";
}
```

This fetch method is called to retrieve the contact details when the user clicks on the link on a jsp

```
<td><a href="fetch/${contact.id}" class="edit">Edit</a></td>
```

It then successfully returns the contact object and displays on the screen for the user to change and save. The form tag of my jsp is like this

```
<form:form method="post" action="add.html" commandName="contact"
        id="contact" onsubmit="return validateContact(this)">
```

Now the problem is when I try to submit the page to another method in the same controller the URL changes to

*/myapp/app/contacts/fetch/add.html*

whereas it should be

*/myapp/app/contacts/add.html*

I know there is something which I am not doing correctly but what exactly I am not able to figure out. Appreciate if any one of you could help me resolve the issue

Thanks
AA

Answer (score 8):

Use

```
<c:url var="addUrl" value="/contacts/add.html"/>
<form:form method="post" action="${addUrl}" commandName="contact"
      id="contact" onsubmit="return validateContact(this)">
```

In general, it is recomended to use `c:url` in every application internal instead of direct use of the url in a `<a>` tag.

Comment: @NimChimpsky c:url has some internal url rewriting, for example the for the seesion key (if cookies are not enalbed/supported). But also some other libs hack into this rewriting (I think the tomcat CSRF-Filter use it too) . An other reason is, that it has included url encoding for the properties.

Comment: Tomcats: CSRF Filter Description: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#CSRF_Prevention_Filter

Answer (score 1):

```
<form:form method="post" servletRelativeAction="/contacts/add" commandName="contact"
        id="contact" onsubmit="return validateContact(this)">
```

Use attribute servletRelativeAction to map to desired controller action. I assume that your desired controller is mapped as '/contacts/add' not 'add.html'. You want to hit the controller not the view.

Answer (score 0):

Use `/contacts/add.html` in `action` attribute
Change

```
<form:form method="post" action="add.html" commandName="contact"
        id="contact" onsubmit="return validateContact(this)">
```

to

```
<form:form method="post" action="/contacts/add.html" commandName="contact"
        id="contact" onsubmit="return validateContact(this)">
```