# Spring MVC - Hibernate mapped object partially filled when using POST request method

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc, hibernate-mapping

Since I've decided to use same JSP for adding and editing posts, I just pass an attribute "saveUrl" which defines the action for my form in the JSP. Adding a new post works fine, but when editing a post, the object returned to the controller is missing all attributes except for the description.

What am I missing or doing wrong here?

Thanks for help!

*My controller:*

```
@Controller 
public class BlogController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BlogController.class);

    @Autowired
    private BlogPostManager bpManager;

    @Autowired
    private UserManager usrManager;

    .....

    @RequestMapping(value = "addPost", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String addPost(Locale locale, Model model, Principal principal) {
        model.addAttribute("post", new BlogPostEntity());
        /** some more code here **/
        return "addEditPost";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "addPostProcess", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addPostProcess(Locale locale, Model model, Principal principal,  @ModelAttribute("post") BlogPostEntity blogPost) {
        blogPost.setDate(new Date());
        blogPost.setAuthor(usrManager.getUser(principal.getName()));
        bpManager.addBlogPost(blogPost);
        return "redirect:/latest";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "editPost/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String editPost(Locale locale, Model model, Principal principal, @PathVariable Integer id) {
        model.addAttribute("post", bpManager.getBlogPost(id));
        model.addAttribute("username", getUsername(principal));
        model.addAttribute("saveUrl", "");
        return "addEditPost";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "editPost/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String editPostProcess(Locale locale, Model model, Principal principal, @ModelAttribute("post") BlogPostEntity blogPost) {
        bpManager.updateBlogPost(blogPost);
        return "redirect:/latest";
    }

        /** some private methods **/

    }
```

*addEditPost.jsp*

> **NOTE: this jsp is acting as a body of Apache tiles.**

```
<h2>Create new post:</h2>
<form:form modelAttribute="post" action="${saveUrl}" method='POST'>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="title">Title:</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="title"></form:input></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="description">Description:</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="description"></form:input></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="text">Text:</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="text"></form:input></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input value="Save" type="submit"></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</form:form>
```

*The mapped BlogPost class:*

```
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "BLOGPOST")
public class BlogPostEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "TITLE", nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION", length = 500)
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "TEXT", length = 5000)
    private String text;

    @Column(name = "DATE")
    private Date date;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = UserEntity.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "authorid", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private UserEntity author;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setAuthor(UserEntity author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    public UserEntity getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

}
```

*DAO for blogpost:*

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.danizmax.simpleblog.entity.BlogPostEntity;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository("blogpostdao")
public class BlogPostDaoImpl implements BlogPostDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public void addBlogPost(BlogPostEntity blogPost) {
        getSession().persist(blogPost);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeBlogPost(int id) {
        BlogPostEntity entity = (BlogPostEntity) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().load(BlogPostEntity.class, id);
        if (entity != null) {
            getSession().delete(entity);
        }
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<BlogPostEntity> latest() {
        List<BlogPostEntity> result = new ArrayList<BlogPostEntity>();
        try {
            result = getSession().createQuery("FROM BlogPostEntity ORDER BY 'id' desc LIMIT 5;").list();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<BlogPostEntity> listPosts(int userId) {
        List<BlogPostEntity> result = new ArrayList<BlogPostEntity>();
        try {
            result = getSession().createQuery("FROM UserEntity").list();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public void updateBlogPost(BlogPostEntity blogPost) {
        blogPost = getBlogPost(blogPost.getId());
        getSession().update(blogPost);
    }

    @Override
    public BlogPostEntity getBlogPost(int id) {
        return (BlogPostEntity) getSession().get(BlogPostEntity.class, id);

    }

    private Session getSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

}
```

UPDATE: I've been experimenting a bit and tried method from [HERE](http://www.techzoo.org/tutorials/java-tutorials/springmvc-hibernate-crud-tutorial-using-eclipse.html), but the object returned to the controler was still empty.

Then I changed the saveURL in JSP to (I read it might be important [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12418427/spring-mapping-forms-action-to-the-controller)):

```
<c:url var="addUrl" value="/secure/postProcess"/>
    <form:form modelAttribute="post" action="${addUrl}" method='POST'>
```

and now the object is filled, only the id is still empty. So there is something probably wrong with the JSP.

Comment: Please show this class BlogPostManager. I think the problem is there

Comment: The problem already occurs when object blogPost is being returned in method editPostProcess(). The blogPost has only description populated, everything else is null. So it happens before the service is used.

Comment: I posted the DAO for blogPost since it contains all DB logic and service no logic yet.

Comment: on addEditPost are you getting all the properties like title,text and description. if you are getting all values there then you should get it in controller also. Can you confirm.

Comment: Yes in addEditPost the object is being inserted fully and the form is being filled too. Something is wrong between clicking submit and recieving it in the controller method editPostProcess().